# wordpress image showing up multiple times

Tags: php, image, wordpress

I am writing a wordpress theme, and have run into a fairly basic problem. By default, when you inset an image into the post, it displays that image at the size you specify, on both the homepage and the single post.

I would like to have different sized images, displaying a thumbnail on the homepage, and a full sized image when you click through to the post. I am using wordpress 2.9's new thumbnail feature, which has created great thumbnails for the homepage. But now, I am stuck with a nice thumbnail next to a large photo (on the index/home page). On the single page, it is displaying correctly with just the large picture.

Basically, I need to know how to tell wordpress to only display the large post image on the single page, not on the index.

Also: I have used the timthumb script, but I think the answer is far more basic then needing plugins or scripts

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code in question so we can see the function you are calling?

Comment: There is no specific code... Just knowing what to do in this situation....Im sure this is a fairly common issue, because i often see wordpress blogs with one thumbnail on the main page and a larger version on the single page. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be completely, 100% achieved using 2.9's thumbnail feature in combination with timthumb. To do so, follow these directions:

in the functions.php file insert:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

In your index.php file, insert:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(array( 125,125 )); ?>
```

And finally, in your single.php, insert:

```
<?php
    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        echo '<div class="post-tnail"><a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'"><img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/scripts/timthumb.php?src='.$thumbnail[0].'&amp;w=440&amp;zc=1&amp;q=95" alt="'.get_the_title().'" /></a></div>';
    }
?>
```

Basically, the functions.php add allows you to see the thumbanil feature on the back-end. Add a new thumbnail and it will display in the box. The homepage will automatically render the 125 x 125 thumbnail, and the single page will automatically render a proportional image with a fixed width of 440px. Took me forever to figure out, but this works!

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely happening is that you need to define an excerpt for that post to display on the home page so that the post_content isn't used along with the post_thumbnail. The drawback to this is that your full post won't display on the front page (or any other list page like category and search pages).